# Reactive conditional template rendering

Tags: templates, meteor

This Meteor code needs to render the correct template based on the value of a helper `display` which works on start up but when it's value changes later via some click events, and the value in the `display` changes from "mainMenu" to "content", the code does not re-render the code with the correct template.

```js
Template.registerHelper('display', () => {
  return Session.get('display');
});
```

```html
<template name="index">
  {{#if (display 'mainMenu')}}
    {{> mainMenu}}
  {{else}} {{#if (display 'content')}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template="content" data=taskInputs}}
  {{/if}}{{/if}}
</template>
```

Why is it not working and how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Why does not your helper accept any parameter?

Comment: I did not need to, but why did you ask? does it have to?

Comment: You have a helper method without any params, which returns a value from Session, but you provide params like 'mainMenu', 'content' while you are calling this helper?

Comment: @Areca Oh. I see. I wanted to get what's in the session and if it is mainMenu then show the mainMenu template but if the value "content" then show the content template. So it looks like I don't know how to use this mechanism.

Comment: Then the function definition would be `displayedTemplate => Session.get('display') === displayedTemplate` so that you can use the passed parameter and run whatever logic you want to run in the function's body.

Comment: Simply `Template.registerHelper('display', displayedTemplate => Session.get('display') === displayedTemplate)`

Comment: @Kyll Yes. thanks that works. I need to brush up on ES6, ;)

Comment: You may want to read a bit about [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
Template.registerHelper('display', (input) => {
  return Session.get('display')==input;
});

Template.index.onCreated(function() {
  Session.set('display',null);
});
```

and

```
<template name="index">
  {{#if display 'mainMenu'}}
    {{> mainMenu}}
  {{else}} 
    {{#if display 'content'}}
      {{> Template.dynamic template="content" data=taskInputs}}
    {{/if}}
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

It works for me.